# Unable to deploy the war in docker web-logic container

Tags: docker, weblogic12c, docker-container, docker-command

Created Docker image for Oracle-12.2.1.2.0 image created successfully and running also on https://localhost:9002/console.

Now I want to deploy my war in this container, using following commands inside container for that -

```
java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://localhost:9002 -username weblogic - 
password weblogic1 -deploy -name Demo-Web -targets AdminServer -source 
D:\Demo-Web.war
```

got issue like

```
Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.Deployer
```

same issue coming outside the conatiner also, so i added -cp $CLASSPATH

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://localhost:9002 - 
username weblogic -password weblogic1 -deploy -name Demo-Web -targets 
AdminServer -source D:\Demo-Web.war
```

old issue got resolved but following issues started coming -

```
Unrecognized option: -adminurl
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I am stuck in this, Please help if anybody face or solved this. I used following link to get help

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/wldeployer.html#1003708

***I am using windows machine as host to deploy and creating images.***

Answer (score 0):

try using java path in the command, it resolved my issue.
which java
/usr/bin/java

/usr/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://localhost:9002 - 
username weblogic -password weblogic1 -deploy -name Demo-Web -targets 
AdminServer -source D:\Demo-Web.war